# jQuery type function as a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, variables

can I create a variable that is a function of this type:

```
jQuery.fn.appendValueToTextArea = function(txt){
  return this.each(function(){
    this.value += txt;
  });
};
```

?

I tried putting a `var` in front of it but I get a error.

Comment: confused.  do you want var myfunction = function() {} or something else?

Comment: Could you clarify your question? You tried putting a `var` in front of what? You want to create a _variable_ that is a _function_ of _which_ type? Your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: Your code seems to do what you're trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/L8fSn/

Comment: well jquery functions can be called like this: `element.appendValueToTextArea('sometext')` I want to create a function that can be called like that, but I want the function to be a variable, like the one John posted above

Comment: I also am here to vote **confused**.  Can you give an example of a function that you would describe as "a variable"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to call a method on an element like you wrote in the comment, you definitely have to extend `jQuery.func`.

Maybe you just want to store the name in a variable?

```
var name = 'appendValueToTextArea'; 
element[name]('text');
```

The only other way is to store a reference to the function and use [**`.call()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [**`.apply()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/function/apply):

```
var func = jQuery.fn.appendValueToTextArea = function(txt) {
    // ...
};

func.call(element, 'text');
```

Or (as I am not sure what you really want) you can assign the function to a variable first and then assign it to `jQuery.fn.appendValueToTextArea`:

```
var func = function(txt) {
    // ...
};

jQuery.fn.appendValueToTextArea = func;
```

Answer (score 2):

What happens if you define the variable *after* the function has been defined?

i.e.

```
jQuery.fn.appendValueToTextArea = function(txt){
  return this.each(function(){
    this.value += txt;
  });
};

var fn = jQuery.fn.appendValueToTextArea;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery.fn.appendValueToTextArea = function(txt){
  return this.each(function(){
    this.value += txt;
  });
};

//This would put the function above in a variable. 
//However, I'm not exactly sure what this gains you    
var myfunction = jQuery.fn.appendValueToTextArea;
```